# Removing repositories from composer.json without deleting the files from project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am new to composer. I am trying to require facebook sdk in my composer but there are other package that are not already accessible in the repo. How can I update my composer and removing the package not available from repo without deleting them on my project. Thanks for you response.

Comment: Did you try ```composer update ``` ?

Comment: yes but removing the repositories will delete modules from my laravel project.

Comment: I just want to add new library so that I can use composer update. Is that possible ? because the repo that was used for that modules are not already available. So I need to remove them from the json and run composer update without deleting them

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this

```
composer remove ip2location/ip2location-laravel
```

[image]

Replace ip2location/ip2location-laravel with your require repository.